# Spark in docker parquet error No predefined schema found

Tags: apache-spark, docker, parquet, sparkr

I have a https://github.com/gettyimages/docker-spark based local spark test cluster including R. In particular, this image is used: https://hub.docker.com/r/possibly/spark/

Trying to read a parquet file with **sparkR** this exception occurs. Reading a parquet file works without any problems on a local spark installation.

```
     myData.parquet <- read.parquet(sqlContext, "/mappedFolder/myFile.parquet")
16/03/29 20:36:02 ERROR RBackendHandler: parquet on 4 failed
Fehler in invokeJava(isStatic = FALSE, objId$id, methodName, ...) : 
  java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: No predefined schema found, and no Parquet data files or summary files found under file:/mappedFolder/myFile.parquet.
    at scala.Predef$.assert(Predef.scala:179)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetRelation$MetadataCache.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$parquet$ParquetRelation$MetadataCache$$readSchema(ParquetRelation.scala:512)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetRelation$MetadataCache$$anonfun$12.apply(ParquetRelation.scala:421)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetRelation$MetadataCache$$anonfun$12.apply(ParquetRelation.scala:421)
    at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetRelation$MetadataCache.refresh(ParquetRelation.scala:421)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetRelation.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$parquet$ParquetRelation$$metadataCac
```

Strangely the same error is the same - even for not existing files.

However in the terminal I can see that the files are there:

```
    /mappedFolder/myFile.parquet
    root@worker:/mappedFolder/myFile.parquet# ls
    _common_metadata                                              part-r-00097-e5221f6f-e125-4f52-9f6d-4f38485787b3.gz.parquet  part-r-00196-e5221f6f-e125-4f52-9f6d-4f38485787b3.gz.parquet
....
```

Comment: In such cases, I'd rather open an issue on the project's tracker. It can be anything in this case. How did you define /mappedFolder?

Comment: I defined it like
`volumes:
      - ./someLocalPath/:/mappedFolder`

Comment: Is this folder mounted? Access your VM first, and check. I guess this is due to some vbox unmounted folders...

Comment: nope it is mounted as `root@worker:/mappedFolder/myFile.parquet# ls` return the files

Comment: As you suggested I created an Issue for this https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-14250

Comment: The local file seems to have been corrupted trying to read it from docker.

Comment: If that was the reason, maybe you could answer your own question and state what the issue was, and how you solved it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My initial parquet file seems to have been corrupted during my test runs of the dockerized spark.

To solve: re-create parquet files from original sources